# Switch paragraphs using inner HTML in JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to switch two paragraphs after clicking the button but I am stuck. Is there any way how to do this using inner HTML without using IF or boolean? I tried this code but it doesn't work. Thanks

```
let elmsButton = document.querySelectorAll("button")[0];
let elmsParagraf1 = document.querySelectorAll(".prvni")[0];
let elmsParagraf2 = document.querySelectorAll(".druhy")[0];

elmsButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    elmsParagraf1.innerHTML = "<div class='druhy'></div>"
    elmsParagraf2.innerHTML = "<div class='prvni'></div>"
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what "switch" means. You want to change their positons as siblings ?  In your code you are trying to nest the elements inside each others not switching them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use `querySelector` in place of using `querySelectorAll` and choose the first element?

By the way, I advise to delete and re-add the elements from the parent rather than using `innerHTML`. The use of `innerHTML` would not preserve listeners and have worse performances:

```
let elmsButton = document.querySelector("button");
let elmsParagraf1 = document.querySelector(".prvni");
let elmsParagraf2 = document.querySelector(".druhy");

elmsButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    swapElements(elmsParagraf1, elmsParagraf2);
});

function swapElements(elem1, elem2) {
  // Check if siblings
  if (elem1.parentElement !== elem2.parentElement) {
    console.error('No sibling elements!');
    return;
  }
  elem1.replaceWith(elem2.cloneNode(true));
  elem2.replaceWith(elem1.cloneNode(true));
}
```

Example:

```js
let elmsButton = document.querySelector("button");

elmsButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let elmsParagraf1 = document.querySelector(".prvni");
    let elmsParagraf2 = document.querySelector(".druhy");
    swapElements(elmsParagraf1, elmsParagraf2);
});

function swapElements(elem1, elem2) {
  // Check if siblings
  if (elem1.parentElement !== elem2.parentElement) {
    console.error('No sibling elements!');
    return;
  }
  elem1.replaceWith(elem2.cloneNode(true));
  elem2.replaceWith(elem1.cloneNode(true));
}
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>

<div class="prvni">I am the first div</div>
<div class="druhy">I am the second div</div>
```

Comment: "The use of innerHTML would not preserve listeners and have worse performances" Are you sure about that? I'd say it is quite the opposite. InnerHTML preserves listeners while cloning the nodes will remove them.

Comment: Yes, innerHTML is just HTML under the form of text, so if there's a listener in your JS it will get lost after `innerHTML`. Also, if you use `innerHTML` the browser will need to parse the text in order to create the internal objects, those internal objects are already there when you just re-use an object. I know that in my snippet I used `cloneNode(true)`, but I'm sure that also cloning is faster than re-parsing :)

Comment: `elem1.replaceWith(elem2.cloneNode(true));
  elem2.replaceWith(elem1.cloneNode(true));` don't you need to use a temp object to put the value of elem1 in it? I think now both element will have the same value.

Comment: If you really want to just switch the order of the paragraphs, why not just use CSS for even better performance since then no reconstructing of the DOM will be needed?

Comment: And what about textContent then? From what i understood, this question is just about swapping text, so no need to worry about listeners.

Comment: Thanks guys, all these solutions work well.

Answer (score 2):

Assign each `DOM.innerHTML` of paragraph to a `variable` then swap them like below example:

```js
let elmsButton = document.querySelectorAll("button")[0];
let elmsParagraf1 = document.querySelectorAll(".prvni")[0];
let elmsParagraf2 = document.querySelectorAll(".druhy")[0];

elmsButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const p1 =  elmsParagraf1.innerHTML;
    const p2 =  elmsParagraf2.innerHTML
    elmsParagraf1.innerHTML = p2;
    elmsParagraf2.innerHTML = p1
});
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
<div class='prvni'>Paragraph 1</div>
<div class='druhy'>Paragraph 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch those two divs by creating a temporary variable that holds Paragraf1 and then change Paragraf1 to Paragraf2 and vice versa, but with the variable.

```
    let temp = elmsParagraf1.innerHTML;
    elmsParagraf1.innerHTML = elmsParagraf2.innerHTML
    elmsParagraf2.innerHTML = temp
```